# How to install abandoned packages with composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I am trying to restore an old project and have to install the **exact** same packages with my composer.

When executing `composer install` I'm getting the following errors:

```
Package fabpot/php-cs-fixer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer instead.
Package oyejorge/less.php is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/php-token-stream is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package sjparkinson/static-review is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use phpro/grumphp instead.
Package zendframework/zend-code is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-code instead.
Package zendframework/zend-config is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-config instead.
Package zendframework/zend-console is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-console instead.
Package zendframework/zend-crypt is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-crypt instead.
Package zendframework/zend-di is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-di instead.
Package zendframework/zend-escaper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-escaper instead.
Package zendframework/zend-eventmanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-eventmanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-filter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-filter instead.
Package zendframework/zend-form is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-form instead.
Package zendframework/zend-http is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-http instead.
Package zendframework/zend-i18n is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-i18n instead.
Package zendframework/zend-inputfilter is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-inputfilter instead.
Package zendframework/zend-json is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-json instead.
Package zendframework/zend-loader is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-loader instead.
Package zendframework/zend-log is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-log instead.
Package zendframework/zend-math is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-math instead.
Package zendframework/zend-modulemanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-modulemanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-mvc is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-mvc instead.
Package zendframework/zend-serializer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-serializer instead.
Package zendframework/zend-server is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-server instead.
Package zendframework/zend-servicemanager is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-servicemanager instead.
Package zendframework/zend-soap is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-soap instead.
Package zendframework/zend-stdlib is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-stdlib instead.
Package zendframework/zend-text is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-text instead.
Package zendframework/zend-uri is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-uri instead.
Package zendframework/zend-validator is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-validator instead.
Package zendframework/zend-view is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-view instead.
```

Is it possible somehow to install those packages despite the errors?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Those are warnings, not errors. If you check whether the packages are installed then you should see that they are there.